# Setup VSFTP to download file not symlink

Tags: configuration, symlink, ftp

I am running VSFTP.

In a chroot environment I have the following setup:

```
ftpdir/directory1
ftpdir/file1.txt
ftpdir/links/linktodirectory1 -> ../directory1
ftpdir/links/linktofile1.txt -> ../file1.txt
```

Where `ftpdir/links/linktodirectory1` is a symbolic link to `ftpdir/directory1` and `ftpdir/links/linktofile1.txt` is a symbolic link to `ftpdir/file1.txt`.

If I transfer `ftpdir/links/linktodirectory1` I get the entire directory, but if I transfer `ftpdir/links/linktofile1.txt` I only get the symbolic link. On the computer I have downloaded it to this symbolic link is broken.

Is there a way to tell VSFTP to follow the symbolic link and download the file?

Answer (score 2):

Originally VSFTP doesn't follow symlinks. Even if you are symlinking stuff inside chrooted folder it will not work. Use hard links or Proftpd i think was able to do it.